Drawing a 24-bit BitmapSource consumes more memory than a 32-bit BitmapSource
I've noticed an issue with memory consumption when drawing bitmaps. A pixel format of 24 bits seems to use way more memory than a format of 32 bits.
I created a simple test to demonstrate. It draws 1024 bitmaps in a grid.
private static int _width = 512, _height = 512;
private static PixelFormat _format = PixelFormats.Bgra32; // <---- cause for concern
private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[_width * _height * _format.BitsPerPixel / 8];

private static BitmapSource CreateBitmap()
{
    int stride = _width * _format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
    return BitmapSource.Create(_width, _height, 96, 96, _format, null, _buffer, stride);
}

public void AddBitmaps(DrawingGroup drawingGroup)
{
    for (int y = -16; y < 16; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = -16; x < 16; x++) 
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = CreateBitmap();
            bitmapSource.Freeze();

            Rect rect = new(x * _width, y * _height, _width, _height);
            ImageDrawing drawing = new(bitmapSource, rect);

            drawingGroup.Children.Add(drawing);
        }
    }
}

When the pixel format is set to 'Bgra32' the memory taken up is about 1 GB. Which is what I expect when drawing 1024 1 MB bitmaps. However, upon setting the pixel format to 'Bgr24' and recompiling, memory consumption increases to 1.8 GB. I expected to see around 800 MB.
I have two questions:

Why does this behavior happen?
How can I lower my memory usage when using the 24-bit pixel format?


It seems that 24-bit bitmaps are internally converted to 32-bit without releasing the buffer. That's why you observe a memory consumption of the 1GB+800MB. If you write ImageDrawing drawing = new(new FormatConvertedBitmap(bitmapSource, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0d), rect); you see no additional memory consumption. If you want to save memory, use only 32-bit formats.

might want to consider posting this an answer ?
